# Copy data from S3 bucket in one AWS account to S3 bucket in other AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy S3 bucket objects from one AWS to another AWS account. I have followed this link [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/) it works with one account A but gives Access Denied error when i used it with another account B. What could be the possible reason for that? Is it related to some firewalls or security issues, even the source account B bucket has been made public.
This is the policy applied to source bucket B

```
{

  "Version": "2012-10-17",

  "Statement": [

    {

      "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",

      "Effect": "Allow",

      "Principal": {

        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:user/abc"

      },

      "Action": [

        "s3:ListBucket",

        "s3:GetObject"

      ],

      "Resource": [

        "arn:aws:s3:::sourceBucketB/*",

        "arn:aws:s3:::sourceBucketB"

      ]

    }

  ]

}
```

This is policy applied to destination account

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

[here are the configurations of bucket from account B][image][1\

I'm using the following command to copy from bucket B to destination account (using destination account profile)

aws s3 sync s3://sourceBucket s3://destinationBucket

Here is the error

> fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
>   ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Comment: Most likely this is a permissions issue. Have you configured security groups?

Comment: The source account B gave us just credentials. Don’t know exactly there security infrastructure. I have attached there configurations. Does it have to do with ‘requester pay’ thing?

Comment: I have tried it. It's working with every test account except the one which actually needs to be connected. I think the issue is because of 'Requester Pays' option enabled with this account or may be some firewall. Because it doesn't allow anonymous access.

Answer (score 2):

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html) contains the exact policy you require and the necessary steps.

According to that documentation, the policy should look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
     {
        "Sid": "Example permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
        },
        "Action": [
           "s3:GetBucketLocation",
           "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I was doing it other way round. I was adding this policy in bucket B with principal of destination account. Do i need to set the user id of Account B?

Comment: But the method i’m following, works well with account A. What’s the difference.

Comment: The example I linked lets Account B have access to Account A's S3 bucket, if that's what you need, then do it this way. If you attach the policy the other way, then Account A will have access to Account B (the way you have it right now), but Account B won't have access to Account A.

Comment: I have tried it. It's working with every test account except the one which actually needs to be connected. I think the issue is because of 'Requester Pays' option. Because it doesn't allow anonymous access.

Answer (score -2):

The easy way (grant all):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also this seems unnecessary and could complicate things (in your second policy):

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*"
            ]
        },
```

Comment: This may get things work, but in general create security breaches. One needs to keep permissions limited to relevant resources only.